# Left Join with temporary RANK() column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to LEFT JOIN a column where the values are calculated using rank() with a lookup column from another table (Points).

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT *, id, Entry.Fin_place, Athlete.First_name, Athlete.Last_name, 
      Fin_Time, Points.Fin_points, Athlete.Ath_no,
      Athlete.Team_no,Team.Team_no,Team.Team_abbr, 
      DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY `Fin_Time` DESC) AS rankz 
FROM `Entry` 
LEFT JOIN Athlete ON Entry.Ath_no = Athlete.Ath_no
LEFT JOIN Team ON Athlete.Team_no = Team.Team_no
LEFT JOIN Points ON rankz = Points.Fin_place;
```

MySQL said: #1054 - Unknown column 'rankz' in 'on clause'

The temporary Rank() value must to be used to look up and display the Fin_points from the Points table, but I keep getting the error message.

Some more info for context:
The **Entry** table:
[image]
The blank column is where the Rankz value must be used to lookup the value of Fin_points in the **Points** table

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qualifying column names with the table or table alias is helpful when posting so we can see where the code could be split. ASSUMING fin_time exists in one of the first 3 invoked tables you could park that lump of code in a cte and join points eg

```
with cte as
(
SELECT *, id, Entry.Fin_place, Athlete.First_name, Athlete.Last_name, 
      Fin_Time, #Points.Fin_points, 
      Athlete.Ath_no,
      Athlete.Team_no,Team.Team_no,Team.Team_abbr, 
      DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY `Fin_Time` DESC) AS rankz 
FROM `Entry` 
LEFT JOIN Athlete ON Entry.Ath_no = Athlete.Ath_no
LEFT JOIN Team ON Athlete.Team_no = Team.Team_no
)
select * , Points.Fin_points
from cte
LEFT JOIN Points ON rankz = Points.Fin_place;
```

The reason your code errors is because rankz does not exists at the time of the join.

Comment: Hi, I'am getting the following error:

Unrecognized statement type. (near "with" at position 0)
SQL query: Copy Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT *, id, Entry.Fin_place, Athlete.First_name, Athlete.Last_name,
     ...' at line 2

Comment: Apologies lost opening bracket after as - code edited.